# How was this probability of negative U.S rates by end 2017 calculated?

Tags: options, interest-rates, yield

http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-01-26/bets-on-negative-u-s-rates-by-end-2017-jump-above-10-chance

> Options markets show some investors are taking out protection in case
>   rates instead go negative. The implied probability of U.S. interest
>   rates sinking below zero next year has risen above 10 percent, data
>   compiled by Bloomberg show.

The bloomberg article was published on 27Jan2016.

Comment: It says right in the article : based on call options on futures contracts linked to LIBOR